# split string into multiple string based on number of item in square brackets C#

Tags: c#, string

this is my string:

```
WARNING: 121 - VT PUMP Manual Pick Required for {[60,70]} HP {["Water Feature","Transfer"]} Pump!
```

I want to split this string into multiple strings based on number of item in square brackets.

```
WARNING: 121 - VT PUMP Manual Pick Required for 60 HP "Water Feature" Pump!
WARNING: 121 - VT PUMP Manual Pick Required for 70 HP "Transfer" Pump!
```

Comment: But not `60 Transfer` and `70 Water Feature`?

Answer (score 1):

my 2 ct (.NET5):

```
    string pumpMsg = "WARNING: 121 - VT PUMP Manual Pick Required for {[60,70]} HP {[\"Water Feature\",\"Transfer\"]} Pump!";
    var rx1 = new Regex(@"^(?<start>.+?)\{\[(?<numbers>[\d \,]+)\]\}(?<middle>.+?)\{\[(?<names>[\w \,""]+)\]\}(?<end>.*)$");
    var match1 = rx1.Match(pumpMsg);
    
    if (!match1.Success)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    var g         = match1.Groups;
    var splitOpts = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries;
    var numbers   = g["numbers"].Value.Split(',', splitOpts).ToArray();
    var names     = g["names"].Value.Split(',', splitOpts).ToArray();
    
    if (names.Length != numbers.Length)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    List<string> messages = Enumerable.Range(0, numbers.Length)
                         .Select(i => $"{g["start"].Value}{numbers[i]}{g["middle"].Value}{names[i]}{g["end"].Value}")
                         .ToList();

 /* result:
  WARNING: 121 - VT PUMP Manual Pick Required for 60 HP "Water Feature" Pump!
  WARNING: 121 - VT PUMP Manual Pick Required for 70 HP "Transfer" Pump!
 */
```

Comment: it would not work for the following string : "WARNING: 121 - VT PUMP Manual Pick Required for [\"a\",\"b\"] [60,70] HP [\"Water Feature\",\"Transfer\"] Pump!"

Comment: Maybe you should introduce your use-cases, data and preconditions in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by the following logic.

```
// text: WARNING: 121 - VT PUMP Manual Pick Required for [60,70] HP [\"Water Feature\",\"Transfer\"] Pump!

public static List<string> CreateMultipleStringsOnTheNumberOfItemsInBracket(string text)
{
    List<string> lstStrings = new List<string>();
    MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, @"\[(.*?)\]");
    int? iterationCount = matchCollection?[0].Value.Split(',').Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterationCount; i++)
    {
        string msg = text;
        for (int a = 0; a < matchCollection.Count; a++)
        {
            string str = Regex.Matches(msg, @"\[(.*?)\]")?[0].Value.ToString();
            string replaceValue = matchCollection[a].Value.Split(',')[i].Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
            msg = msg.Replace(str, replaceValue);
        }
        lstStrings.Add(msg);
    }
    return lstStrings;
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this code works and how it answer the question?

Comment: There is no `resultList` in the question. There is no `ExceptionMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar solution using a Match Evaluator.  Not sure if that much better

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ConsoleApplication193
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "WARNING: 121 - VT PUMP Manual Pick Required for [60, 65, 70] HP [\"Water Feature\",\"Start\",\"Transfer\"] Pump!";

            List<string> results = MyEvaluator.EnumerateString(input);


        }
    }
    public class MyEvaluator
    {
        static string pattern = @"\[[^\]]+]";
        static int row;
        static int col;
        static string[][] arrays = null;

        public static List<string> EnumerateString(string input)
        {
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            arrays = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value.Split(new char[] { '[', ',', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray()).ToArray();

            // Assign the replace method to the MatchEvaluator delegate.
            MatchEvaluator myEvaluator = new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceCC);
            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            for(int i = 0; i < arrays[0].Length; i++)
            {
                row = i;
                col = 0;
                results.Add(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, myEvaluator));
            }
            return results;
        }

 
        static string ReplaceCC(Match m)
        {

            string output = arrays[col][row].Replace("\"","");
            col++;
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```